# How do I set context in the response json payload?

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks

I have setup a nodeJS server to return responses to a dialogflow webhook. I want to be able to send back a context in the JSON response so that dialogflow logic can move to the next desired Intent in the conversation flow.

In the response payload, I tried inserting "outputContexts" array in order to set the context. However this is not working in this form. The response Json is pasted below. The variable contextName holds the desired value of context to be sent back.

```
var simpleResponse = {
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "outputContexts": [
        {
          "name": "projects/my-agent-v2/agent/sessions/" + sessionId + "/contexts/" + contextName,
          "lifespanCount": 1,
          "parameters": {
            "param": "param value"
          }
        }
      ],
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Simple response",
              "displayText": "Simple response"
            }
}]}}}};
```

The control should move to intent = awaiting_more_details. The above returned context is the "input context" to this intent.

I hope this gives an understanding about what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response has the wrong format, the `outputContexts` array must be in the top level object, next to `payload`. See Dialogflow's [Discovery document](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis) for the authoritative specification: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dialogflow/v2beta1/rest

Comment: (And you also don't need to set the displayText like this, Dialogflow will automatically use the textToSpeech if it is not given.)

Comment: How many text messages I can have inside of richResponse.Items? I have tried 4 but only the first 2 are being displayed on the chat bot UI. Any comments will be apppreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Two is the maximum at the moment: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#richresponse

Comment: true. It seems no other option, but to manage things within 2 bubbles

Comment: Is there a way my nodejS server can send events to the dialogflow chat bot?